# Deploying to a specific target in Firebase Hosting

Tags: json, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have the following hosting targets in my **firebase.json** file

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "staging",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "production",
      "public": "build",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my **firebaserc** file contains the following:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "project-name177137"
  },
  "targets": {
    "project-name177137": {
      "hosting": {
        "staging": [
          "project-name177137"
        ],
        "production": [
          "productionName"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I want to deploy to all I usually just do `firebase deploy`.

Now imagine I want to deploy to only **staging** for testing, what firebase command can I use to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
firebase deploy --only hosting:staging
```

[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets#deploy-target-commands)

Comment: Yea, it worked. Thank you